# only width on <img> not working in reactjs

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have tried two ways for styling 1st is inline styling and another is by declaring "mystyle" as a object and pass it as style={myStyle} and m using react-bootstrap/Carousel

```
<Carousel.Item>
     <img
      className="d-block w-100"
      src={img1}
      style={{ height: "100px", width: "50%" }}
      alt="First slide"
     />
     <Carousel.Caption>
        <h3>First slide label</h3>
        <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
     </Carousel.Caption>
</Carousel.Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to alter the specific image in the carousel container. Give the React-Bootstrap Carousel component a class name and then adjust the images to your liking or alter the entire container size to match your specifications. Best of luck!

```
.carousel-container {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 300px;

     .carousel {
        .slide {
            img {
                height: 100%;
                width: auto;
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: only .carousel-container ->max-width,max-height worked. img one didn't work. and the carousel also shifted left on the page

Answer (score 0):

The img tag has width and height attributes you need to use them instead of style prop

```
    <img
       className="d-block w-100"
       src={img1}
       width="500px"
       height="100%" //if you don't give height attribute then it will always be 100%
       alt="First slide"
       />
```

Comment: Tried this one too but still width is not working somehow.